# Sumo, TraCI: Subscription with tc.VAR_ROUTE and tc.VAR_FOLLOWER fails. Which subscription variables can I use for vehicles?

Tags: python, sumo

I want to subscribe to vehicles in my simulation. However, I find it very difficult to understand which variables I can use for this, as the [documentation](https://sumo.dlr.de/pydoc/traci.constants.html) does not include this information.

```
        traci.vehicle.subscribe(veh_id, [
            tc.VAR_SPEED,
            tc.VAR_ACCELERATION,
            tc.VAR_EMERGENCY_DECEL,
            # tc.VAR_ROUTE,
            tc.VAR_POSITION,
            # tc.VAR_FOLLOWER,
            tc.VAR_NEXT_TLS
        ])
```

The issue is, that `tc.VAR_ROUTE` causes this error in the terminal:

```
traci.exceptions.TraCIException: Could not add subscription. Get Vehicle Variable: unsupported variable 0x57 specified
```

and `tc.VAR_FOLLOWER` causes this error in SUMO:

```
Error: Storage::readChar(): invalid position
Quitting (on error).
```

Why is that? Also I do not quite understand how to learn more about the different constants. For example, which ones can I use to subscribe to vehicles?
When I look into the file under `traci/constants.py`, there are different types of variables.

- starting with `CMD_` (the comments call these "command")
- starting with `RESPONSE_` (the comments call these "response")
- starting with `VAR_` (the comments say these are "Variable types (for CMD_GET_*_VARIABLE)")
- stop flags, departure flags, and many more
- Also, the comments sometimes say something like: `(get: ...; set: ...)`

e.g. here:

```
#  position (2D) (get: vehicle, poi, inductionloop, lane area detector; set: poi)
VAR_POSITION = 0x42
```

What does that mean, I know that I can `get` the subscription results from subscribing to these constants, but how could I possibly `set` them?

My main question is if someone can please explain how these constants are structured and which ones I can use for subscribing to vehicles.

Comment: Which SUMO version do you use?

Comment: SUMO 1.9 built from source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right this is not well documented. I added a ticket: https://github.com/eclipse/sumo/issues/8579

The answer to your direct question is that everything which is listed in the value retrieval section of the docs (which should be equivalent to having a "get" in the constants file comment) should be "subscribable".

VAR_ROUTE is not, because it is only used to set a route using the edge list but there is no equivalent getter. You can only subscribe to the route ID for instance. VAR_FOLLOWER in turn needs a parameter when subscribing, so you need to give that as an additional argument. How to do that unfortunately depends on your SUMO version.

For SUMO 1.9 and later the call looks like this:

```
traci.vehicle.subscribe(vehID, (tc.VAR_FOLLOWER,), begin, end, {tc.VAR_FOLLOWER: ("d", dist)})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using SUMO 1.9 and built it from source. So it should include all of the newest stuff. I am currently subscribing to the leader with `traci.vehicle.subscribeLeader()` because passing `tc.VAR_LEADER` also throws the error. However `tc.VAR_FOLLOWER` does not have this kind of replacement method.

Comment: Could you please briefly explain how to pass the additional argument for subscribing to VAR_FOLLOWER if it's possible?

Comment: You can just look at the code of subscribeLeader but I also added an example to the answer